# How to setup AutoMapper in ASP.Net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, .net-6.0

How to configure AutoMapper in ASP.Net Core 6

I have a project which is written in .Net 3.1 so we had Startup.cs class.

I am migrating it to .net core 6

now when I put the following configuration in my .Net 6 Program.cs

```
             builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

I get error the type or namespace Startup could not be found

Any suggestions ?, how can I fix it or configure it in .net 6

Comment: `typeof(Program).Assembly` I referred [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/pz6xmx/setting_up_automapper_in_minimal_api/)

Comment: Your comment is correct, you can post it as Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using this line instead: `typeof(Program).Assembly`

Comment: You can drop the `.Assembly` bit and it'll work just [the same](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/986267d95da70fef4c4811b59065533137bdd304/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L46-L47).

Answer (score 43):

**install package**

- dotnet add package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

in **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

create **MappingProfiles.cs**

```
namespace XXX.XXX.Helpers;

public class MappingProfiles: Profile {
    public MappingProfiles() {
        CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

For those who didn't know like me.

1. Install AutoMapper extension for DI via NuGet or by `dotnet add package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`
2. Then in the Program.cs file register the service with: `builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(<name-of-profile>));` (In .NET 6 we no longer have the StartUp.cs)

I used Profiles to do my mapping configuration. Here's a [link](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) from Automapper about profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to fix:

`builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));`

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same suggestion as that provided by [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216238/3025856)? You root this off a different persistent class (`Program`, not `Startup`), but the basic concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `line of code` in your `Program.cs`.

> services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Install AutoMapper Package(version as per your proj requirement)

```
Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection -Version 9.0.0
```

after that register a service in CinfigureServices on Startup.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
}
```

Comment: Core 6.0 don't have class Startup.cs